# Executar código VBA a partir de arquivo de texto

Tags: vba

Tenho um código em `VBA` que faz uma consulta ao banco e salva em um arquivo de texto, mas pra executar este script tenho que abrir o `Excel` e executar a `macro`, este processo tem que ser realizado de minuto em minuto, pois preciso das informações em tempo real.

É possível rodar esta macro a partir de um arquivo de texto para evitar consumo de memória desnecessário?

Comment: façca como o amigo ali informou, converta seu modulo VBA em VBScript, são bem parecidos e chame sua rotina usando wscript.exe ou cscript.exe dentro da System32 ou SYSWOW64

Comment: Seria interessante você compartilhar seu código pra que pudéssemos lhe ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 10):

Você já tentou criar um arquivo `vbs` (VB Script)? Nesse arquivo você pode usar VB Script para fazer o que quiser, independente do excel. Provavelmente existem algumas diferenças, mas nada que não possa ser adaptado.

Exemplos em VBScript:

**criar-banco.vbs**

```
' criando banco de dados

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=MIGUELANGELO-NB\SQL2008R2; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

On Error Resume Next
    Set command = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    command.ActiveConnection = conn

    command.CommandText = "CREATE DATABASE TestDb"
    command.Execute()
    If Err.Number = 0 Then

        command.CommandText = "     " &_
        "   USE TestDb;             " &_
        "   CREATE TABLE Pessoas    " &_
        "   (                       " &_
        "       id int NOT NULL,    " &_
        "       nome varchar(max),  " &_
        "       PRIMARY KEY (id)    " &_
        "   );                      "
        command.Execute()

        If Err.Number = 0 Then

            command.CommandText = "USE TestDb; INSERT INTO Pessoas (id,nome) VALUES (0, 'Miguel');"
            command.Execute()

            command.CommandText = "USE TestDb; INSERT INTO Pessoas (id,nome) VALUES (1, 'Angelo');"
            command.Execute()

            command.CommandText = "USE TestDb; INSERT INTO Pessoas (id,nome) VALUES (2, 'Santos');"
            command.Execute()

            command.CommandText = "USE TestDb; INSERT INTO Pessoas (id,nome) VALUES (3, 'Bicudo');"
            command.Execute()

        End If
    End If
On Error Goto 0
conn.Close()
```

**ler-banco.vbs**

```
' lendo o banco de dados

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=MIGUELANGELO-NB\SQL2008R2; Initial Catalog=TestDb; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
const ForWriting = 2
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("saida.txt", ForWriting, True)

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM Pessoas;", conn
While Not rs.EOF
    id = rs("id")
    nome = rs("nome")
    file.WriteLine "id = " & id & "; nome = " & nome
    rs.MoveNext()
Wend

rs.Close()
conn.Close()
file.Close()
```

Também é possível usar JScript (JavaScript) ao invés de VBScript.

Para executar basta clicar duas vezes sobre o arquivo que já deve funcionar. A não ser que você tenha associado `.vbs` com outro programa. Neste caso, terá de executar usando linha de comando: `cscript nome-arquivo.vbs`

Comment: Oi Miguel. Vc podia fornecer um exemplo aqui, na sua resposta. :)

Comment: Para isso vou ter que partir de algumas suposições pois a questão não informa quase nada sobre o que está sendo feito no script VBA. Só um instante que vou criar algo. =D

Comment: Só que ele já tem o código VBA, né... Converter para JS pode dar mais trabalho que "converter" para VBS (converter entre aspas porque a diferença é bem pouca entre um e outro). De qualquer modo, depois que eu respondi é que eu vi que isso aqui era caso antigo hehehe (alguém modificou algo e foi parar na lista de perguntas ativas).

Comment: @Caffé Converti para VBScript.

Comment: Valeu Miguel! :)

Answer (score 3):

Você pode Criar um arquivo em lote para chamar seu arquivo de Excel.

```
call C:\diretorio\do\arquivo\ArquivoExcel.xlsm
```

E no seu arquivo de Excel você deixa sua macro como auto executável ao abrir a planilha.

Ex.: se toda vez que o arquivo de excel for aberto você quiser que ele mostre uma mensagem "Bem vindo!"

1 - No VBA você seleciona "Esta pasta de trabalho"

2 - Na aba logo acima, no lugar de Geral, já selecione "Workbook"

O vba vai te dar a linha de comando "Private sub workbook_open()" e então você cola sua macro dentro.

```
Private sub workbook_open()
Msgbox "Bem vindo!"
End sub
```

[image: Chamada VBA]

Pronto. Você pode fechar a planilha e executar o arquivo *.bat* ele irá abrir a planilha e a macro será executada automaticamente.

> **Observação:** Pra ficar melhor ainda, você pode baixar um conversor de ***.bat*** para ***.exe*** e transforma-lo em um aplicativo. Só pra fica mais
>   apresentável (Talvez voce queira que outros usuários façam a execução do mesmo).

Comment: Boa solução, mas não funcionaria para o que foi questionado, pois o autor da pergunta deseja que seja executado a cada X segundos, enquanto que o seu .bat ou .exe dependeria de uma execução manual (não considerando agendamento do Windows, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

A solução é usar VBS em vez Excel VBA, como dito pelo @Miguel Angelo.

Abaixo seguem mais detalhes (eu estava complementando resposta dele mas acabou ficando longo demais).

Primeiro programa em VBS - crie um arquivo chamado ***teste.vbs*** com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
msgbox "Hello, World!"
```

Quando você der duplo-clique no arquivo, esta mensagem será mostrada na tela. Simples assim. O script também pode, naturalmente, ser invocado pelo prompt de comando (vulgo "DOS").

O Excel usa **VBA** (*Visual Basic for Applications*) e este outro método usa **VBS** (*Visual Basic Script*). Há diferenças (por exemplo, em VBS você não especifica o tipo das variáveis) mas é muito fácil converter um no outro. E usando VBS você também consegue acessar os recursos do Excel caso precise.

Exemplo de como acessar a base de dados usando ADO em VBS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429313/a-generic-vbscript-function-to-connect-to-any-database-and-execute-any-sql-query

Exemplo de como ler arquivo texto em VBS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117121/reading-and-writing-value-from-a-textfile-by-using-vbscript-code

Entre estes exemplos e o código que você já tem na macro Excel, as diferenças basicamente são as declarações de variáveis e a maneira de se obter objetos ActiveX. Por exemplo, em VBA no Excel você faz assim:

```
Set conexao = New ADODB.Connection
```

E usando VBS você faz assim:

```
Set conexao = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

Para executar o script a intervalos regulares, você pode usar o **Agendador de Tarefas** do Windows ou pode fazer um loop nó próprio script com um tempo de espera entre as iterações. Por exemplo:

```
WScript.Sleep 1000 * 60
```

O código acima mantém a execução do script parada nesta linha, por um minuto.